# Convert xy coordinates to postgresql geometry in python

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry, coordinates

I'm writing a python algorithm to import a CSV file containing XY coordinates of a point into a postgresql table.
My problem is I don't know how to convert these coordinates into postgresql geometry so that the import works.
for instance, I would like to convert [842507.78, 6612890.36] into something like 01010000206A0800005BB3E9A5A8422941DB32C22CEEB55941

If anyone could help me, i would be grateful :)

Comment: I copied it from what i saw with pgAdmin and the type of my column is geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `st_makePoint`

```
select st_makepoint(827732.324,6739896.69);
```

Comment: Yes I saw this answer in another subject but i tried it and it didn't work. I'm not sure how to use it as well, am i supposed to use it with psycopg2 connection to my database while i'm writing my csv file ?

Comment: Have your Python code generate `INSERT` statements using the function from the answer.

Comment: Nop it's just sending me an error like "FROM is missing from your statement". To make the insert, i'm using the copy_from method which generates a copy statement of my csv file